# If Statements And Braces.. Different Result With/Without

Tags: c++, if-statement, braces

Alright, so I'm in the process of learning C++, and I've hit a strange effect while working with one of the tutorials, and I don't quite get while it's happening..

For the tutorial (copied from the example offered), I have written a function within a class template specialization that checks if the char is lowercase, and then makes it uppercase:

```
char uppercase ()
{
    //checks to see if "element"(char) is a lower-case letter between 'a' and 'z'
    if ((element >= 'a') && (element <= 'z'))
    {
        //changes value of "element" to be element + (value of A - Value of a)[-32]
        element += 'A' - 'a'; //element = element + -32
        return element;
    };
};
```

Now, strangely.. even if the char is already uppercase, this code still gets triggered. So if I call the function with a value of 'j', I obviously get 'J', as intended. However, if I call with a value of 'J', the function still goes through.. so instead of the function not changing anything, it instead returns '*'.

Now, interestingly.. if I remove the brackets from the if statement, it works as intended. So, with

```
char uppercase ()
{
    //checks to see if "element"(char) is a lower-case letter between 'a' and 'z'
    if ((element >= 'a') && (element <= 'z'))
        //changes value of "element" to be element + (value of A - Value of a)[-32]
        element += 'A' - 'a'; //element = element + -32
        return element;
};
```

it works completely as intended. Calling the function with the value 'J' just returns 'J', because the conditions weren't met, and thus no code was executed. Now, I know that braces are optional with if statements, but the tutorial says that braces are required for more than one statement.

It's also worth noting that adding an else to the statement using braces with just a plain return gives the desired effect, but this should be unnecessary, right?

So, basically.. am I missing something about braces, or is this just an issue with the compiler (Visual Studio 2012)?

Comment: `warning C4715: 'uppercase' : not all control paths return a value`. Warnings are there to help you, read them and fix them rather than ignoring them.

Comment: Yeah, I somehow missed the error. I'm normally really good about checking that.. I guess I just didn't expect one in this case.

Comment: What I don't get is why you even care about the return value.  You're modifying something outside the function's scope - unless you forgot to add `char element` to your function's parameter list.  Nobody else seems to have commented on this...

Comment: There's way more code (and like I said, the function is part of a class template specialization), but I didn't "write" any of it.. during the tutorials, I first copy the example (typing out, and modifying/shorting things to a format I prefer as habit). I realize the code is stupid, and inefficient.. but it's the example code. Due to my oversight on the braces placement, I couldn't decide if I missed something, if the compiler was being weird, or if the tutorial example was just genuinely that 1-dimensional and stupid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's per design, the `if` takes one statement only, the braces make a block one statement.

If you want scope by indentation use Python.

The problem with your code is that you do not return anything when the `if` statement does not match, which results in undefined behavior. Your compiler probably gives you a warning about that. Don't ignore compiler warnings.

The second block of code is actually what you want, only change the variable `element` when your `if` matches, but always return the variable `element`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're saying.. the if statement actually functions identically with both snippets, with the exception of the if being used regardless of conditions, when I've braced the statements. If anything, the fact that the two-statement if statement works WITHOUT braces is the most confusing.. if anything, it should be the other way around. I am actually experienced with Python, though.. but I'm branching into others to see which I like the most, in order to move forward with some future projects.

Comment: Ahhh.. you edited it. You answered it. I wasn't even considering the fact that the first statement was the "if", and the return statement was just part of the function. Yep, I totally missed that. Thanks. :)

Comment: No, the problem is that you have undefined behavior when you don't return a value. Both pieces of code are functioning exactly like the standard says they should.

Comment: Nah, I know what you mean.. I just worded my response weirdly. I missed the warning on the compiler. What I was trying to say was that in un-braced version, I was glossing over the fact that the first (element) statement was effectively "braced", and the second (return) was outside of the if conditions. I try to consistently use braces as habit, so in closing off the whole function (how I was thinking it was supposed to work), I was making BOTH statements fall under the conditions. You're absolutely right, it was behaving exactly as it should, just not in the way I thought.

Comment: I see the confusion was because we both typed a reply within a very small time frame.. so you were probably responding to my first reply. When I replied, only the first two lines of your comment were visible.. so I assumed you edited in the rest. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, you are not executing a `return` statement if the condition isn't met.  Presumably the function is returning garbage.

In the second case, because there are no braces, only one line is dependent on the condition.  The `return` statement is executed regardless.  In other words, your second example is equivalent to:

```
char uppercase ()
{
    //checks to see if "element"(char) is a lower-case letter between 'a' and 'z'
    if ((element >= 'a') && (element <= 'z'))
    {
        //changes value of "element" to be element + (value of A - Value of a)[-32]
        element += 'A' - 'a'; //element = element + -32
    }
    return element;
};
```

Comment: Yep, wich edited their comment, and I got the answer I was looking for. I obviously just missed the error listing.. I was totally ignoring the fact that the un-braced version was only including the first statement under the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You have an if statement. If the statement evaluates to true, it will execute the operation immediately following it. In order to do more than one operation at once, you must enclose them in curly braces.

You're getting a strange answer with braces because if J *is* uppercase, your if statement is false, you skip past the braces, and you don't have a specified return value (hence the nonsense return value). You need to say what to return if your if statement *isn't* true.

Your second piece of code works because only the first line after the if statement is controlled by the if. This is essentially you being lucky here with - if you had two operations you had wanted to do, you'd still be getting garbage. It's generally therefore good practice to explicitly specify what code you want executed by your if statement by putting it in curly braces, even if it's one operation.

Comment: Yep, wich edited their comment, and I got the answer I was looking for. I obviously just missed the error listing.. I was totally ignoring the fact that the un-braced version was only including the first statement under the conditions.